# laravel 8 - Return array based user role

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Metronic 8 admin dashboard template for laravel.

The developer made the nav menu as array:

```
<?php
return array(
    // Main menu
    'main' => array(
        //// Dashboard
        array(
            'title' => 'Dashboard',
            'path' => '',
            'icon' => theme()->getSvgIcon("demo1/media/icons/duotune/art/art002.svg", "svg-icon-2") ,
        ) ,
    )
)
```

If you want to add a new nav item, just add an object inside the array. 

I am currently using Spatie user roles & permissions. According to their docs, I can use blade directives like this:

```
@can('permission name')
test
@endcan
```

OR

@role('role name')
test
@endrole

Unfortunately, the `menu.php` is a plain php config file and not a blade.
How can I use spatie to hide nav items based on user role?

**Resources:**

[Metronic laravel docs](https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/laravel/documentation/configuration/menu)

[Spatie docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/basic-usage)

Comment: Why not build the returned array using conditionals for the user's permissions? Quickly looking into the [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/direct-permissions) you can do things like `if($user->hasPermissionTo('permission name')) {`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change configs runtime, in Controller or in Middleware or even in Provider, depending on your needs. You need to do something like:

```
$navs = config('config.global.menu');
if(auth()->user()->can('permission name')){
    $navs[] = 'nav item';
    config([
        'config.global.menu' => $navs
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new listener and bind `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` event to it in `EventServiceProvider`. I've named this event as `ModifyMetronicMenu`.

```php
protected $listen = [
        Login::class=>[
            ModifyMetronicMenu::class
        ]
    ];
```

**ModifyMetronicMenu** listener

```php
namespace App\Listeners;

class ModifyMetronicMenu
{
    public function handle($event)
    {
        $newMenu = array_filter(config('menu.main'),function ($item){
            return \Auth::user()->can(data_get($item,'title'));
        });

        // Update the menu config file
        config(['menu.main'=>$newMenu]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have filtered menu and have updated the config. Notice that the condition that I wrote in the `array_filter` is not correct and you should tune it base on your needs.

Comment: I get this error: ```Call to a member function hasPermissionTo() on null```

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMushref I've updated the answer. As we need an authenticated user to know about his/her permissions, I have bind this filter to *login* event to perform this filter after user logged in.